# Weird behavior when changing line separator and then changing it back

Tags: ruby, multiline, gets

I was following the advice [from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1075233/how-to-get-multiple-line-user-input-in-ruby) when trying to read in multi-line input from the command line:

```
# change line separator
$/ = 'END'
answer = gets
pp answer
```

However, I get weird behavior from `STDIN#gets` when I try to change `$/` back:

```
# put it back to normal
$/ = "\n"
answer = gets
pp answer
pp 'magic'
```

This produces output like this when executed with Ruby:

```
$ ruby multiline_input_test.rb
this is
        a multiline
  awesome input string
                        FTW!!
END
"this is\n\ta multiline\n  awesome input string\n            \t\tFTW!!\t\nEND"
"\n"
"magic"
```

(I input up to the `END` and the rest is output by the program, then the program exits.)

It does not pause to get input from the user after I change `$/` back to `"\n"`. So my question is simple: why?

As part of a larger (but still small) application, I'm trying to devise a way of recording notes; as it is, this weird behavior is potentially devastating, as the rest of my program won't be able to function properly if I can't reset the line separator. I've tried all manner of using double- and single-quotes, but that doesn't seem to be the issue. Any ideas?

Comment: Your description in the last code block is not clear. Which part is the code, which part is the user input, and which part is the response?

Comment: @sawa Sorry about that. The code snippets I provided are all the code that I am executing within 'multiline_input_test.rb'. When that is executed, it pauses, waiting for user input. I typed in "this is a multiline awesome input string FTW!!" (with random whitespace), then typed 'END'. The rest is what was printed out: no other pause when executing the second `gets` from my code.

Comment: it looks like the second `gets` is simply returning a newline that I never typed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you're having is that your input ends with `END\n`.  Ruby sees the `END`, and there's still a `\n` left in the buffer.  You *do* successfully set the input record separator back to `\n`, so that character is immediately consumed by the second `gets`.

You therefore have two easy options:

1. Set the input record separator to `END\n` (use double quotes in order to have the newline character work):

   ```
   $/ = "END\n"
   ```
2. Clear the buffer with an extra call to `gets`:

   ```
   $/ = 'END'
   answer = gets
   gets # Consume extra `\n`
   ```

I consider option 1 clearer.

This shows it working on my system using option 1:

```
$ ruby multiline_input_test.rb 
this is
        a multiline
  awesome input string
                        FTW!!
END
"this is\n        a multiline\n  awesome input string\n                        FTW!!\nEND\n"
test
"test\n"
"magic"
```

Comment: Ahhhh, thank you! I believe you have saved me many minutes of debugging. This makes perfect sense, I was already thinking something along the lines of flushing the buffer, but I, too, like your first option as a better alternative.

Comment: Thanks for the edits to my question, btw :) clarity is always important.